# Can I call server side code using customErrors?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

If I am using customErrors in my Web.config how can utilize any server code before I call this page?

Will I have to handle in my catch statements prior to calling the error?
Is there another option?

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/MyPageError.cshtml" />
```

In my case I want to log the user off the site before it hits my error page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding an ajax get method to the view to call my server side code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create filters in application which can handle your errors for example

```
public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new ErrorHandler());
        }

        public class ErrorHandler : HandleErrorAttribute
        {
            public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
            {
                base.OnException(filterContext);
                SendEmail(filterContext.Exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Register in Global.asax.cs

```
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

mention this on controller

```
[ErrorHandler]
```

you can specify view as well in case of error

```
[ErrorHandler(View = "")]
```

Comment: So I would turn off customErrors in this case and implement the ErrorHandler filter across all of my controllers?

Comment: I tried [ErrorHandler(View = "~/Views/Shared/MyPageError.cshtml")] however it will not display this page.  It's just throwing an ugly error message up to the screen.

Comment: @JDS have you registered it in Global.asax.cs and if yes than use 


[HandleError(View = "")]
[ErrorHandler(View = "")]

Comment: Yes I have: FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters); and the view won't display

Comment: @JDS Keep errors on via<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error" />

In your shared view add the error page in aspx not cshtml
example
[HandleError(View = "Error")]
and add the page under view/shared as Error.aspx